# Finding the maximum volume of a cone

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

21. You have a 6 inch diameter circle of paper which you want to form into a
    drinking cup by removing a pie–shaped wedge and forming the remaining
    paper into a cone (Fig. 22). Find the height and top radius of so the volume of
    the cup is as large as possible.

This is a question from Saylor Academy.
I am working on this problem, and I can understand that the volume is $1/3 \pi r^2 h$. But, I cannot understand how to figure out what h is. The answer key gives it as the $\sqrt{9-r^{2}}$. Why?

Comment: Please provide some more background about what you have tried on the problem and where you are stuck

Comment: Look at the cone from the side, remember the Pythagorean theorem, and you'll see.

Comment: A small comment to help you in your work. After you get the volume to be $V = \frac 13 \pi r^2\sqrt{9-r^2}$, before you differentiate, *square* it first to get $V^2$ as a function of $r$. Remember that for positive $V$, $V^2$ is a monotonically increasing function of $V$, so that means you can work equally well with $V^2$ for this problem. And you don't have to worry about chain and product rule anymore - just square, expand and it's a simple polynomial function that you can easily differentiate and set to zero. Calculating the second derivative (to confirm a maximum) is also trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this side view of your cone  help?

[image]

I answered your question "why."

Answer (score 0):

$V=\frac 13\pi r^2h$.  But by the Pythagorean theorem,  $h^2+r^2=3^2$.

Comment: Sorry - can you explain that a bit further?

Comment: Well, when you form the cone, the height,  top radius,  and circle radius (which is $3$) form a right triangle.